# Table data only shows first letter of entry

Tags: php, html-table

I am printing data from a mysql table into a table on my web page. Here is the code

```
     Print "<table border cellpadding=5>"; 
      Print "<tr><th>Name:</th> <th>Size:</th> <th>Depth:</th> <th>Boat Access:</th>  
      <th>All Sports:</th> <th>Public Beach:</th> <th>Fish Species:</th> <th>Comments:
      </th></tr>"; 
       while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
      {
       Print "<tr>"; 
       Print " <td>".$info['member'] . "</td> "; 
       Print "<td>".$info['size'] . " </td>";
       Print " <td>".$info['depth'] . "</td> "; 
       Print " <td>".$info['access'] . "</td> "; 
       Print " <td>".$info['sports'] . "</td> "; 
       Print " <td>".$info['beach'] . " </td>";
       Print" <td>".$info['bluegill'] ."   </td>";
       Print " <td>".$info['comments'] . "</td> "; "</tr>"; 
       } 
       Print "</table>";
```

It works fine the way it is, but my question is How would I put multiple values in the same table data. I've tried several different ways with nothing working. If I put it 
$info['bluegill'][beach] it only enters the first letter of the first entry into the table.
Any suggestions?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Are you asking how to echo a variable?

Answer (score 3):

concatenate each print like this

```
Print " <td>". $info['member'] . $info['thing'] . "</td> ";
```

this will allow you to echo extra values in each table box

Comment: Thanks a bunch Adam. Could have sworn I tried that, but guess not because it works now.

Comment: You're welcome. I had the exact same problem when starting with PHP :)